# Somar números primos dentro de um vetor

Tags: c, array

Tenho este problema : Faça um algoritmo que receba 1500 números, calcule e mostre a soma dos números pares e a soma dos números primos.

Até ai tudo bem, consegui filtrar e somar os números pares, MAS, a soma dos números primos sempre dá 0.
Eu criei um algoritmo separado para testar se eu consigo achar números primos, ele funciona :

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{


    int numero, i, controle=0;


    printf("Digite um numero: ");


    scanf("%d", &numero);


    if (numero > 1)
    {

        for (i = 1; i <= numero; i = i + 1)
        {


            if (numero % i == 0) 
            {
                controle = controle + 1;    
            }    
        }


        if (controle == 2)
        {
           printf("O numero %d e um numero primo!\n", numero);             
        }
        else
        {
            printf("O numero %d nao e um numero primo!\n", numero);    
        }

    }

}

Porém quando eu aplico ele no programa do exercício, ele não resulta em nada: 



#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


main()

{
    int num[1500], i, par = 0, primo = 0, cont = 0;

    for(i=0; i < 5; i = i + 1)
    {
        printf("\n Digite um numero inteiro: ");
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);






    if(num[i]%2 == 0)
    {
     par = par + num[i];
    }

    }

    printf("\n A soma dos numeros pares: %d", par);


for(i=0; i < 5; i = i + 1)
    {
        if(num[i] > 1)
                {
                    for (i = 1; i <= num[i]; i =  i + 1)
                    {
                        if(num[i] % i == 0)
                        {
                            cont = cont + 1;    
                        }

                    }
                }
        if(cont == 2)
        {
            primo = primo + num[i];
            printf(" t ");
        }
    }
    printf("\n A soma dos numeros primos e: %d", primo);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Parabéns por ter lido as regras antes de postar!! Eu recomendo tirar a primeira frase da pergunta, esse tipo de coisa eu costumo colocar no comentário(mesmo se for da minha própria pergunta). Você esqueceu de colocar a [tag](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags) da linguagem que você está usando, isso ajuda muito para que sua pergunta tenha mais acessos, e portanto seja respondida mais rápido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

é porque você está usando a mesma variável para controlar dois for encadeados:

crie uma variável j e utilize no segundo for.

faltou zerar o cont dentro do for também

Exemplo:

```
int num[1500], i, j, par = 0, primo = 0, cont = 0;

for(i=0; i < 5; i = i + 1)
{
    printf("\n Digite um numero inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d", &num[i]);

    if(num[i]%2 == 0)
    {
     par = par + num[i];
    }
}

printf("\n A soma dos numeros pares: %d", par);


for(i=0; i < 5; i = i + 1)
{
    cont = 0
    if(num[i] > 1)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= num[i]; j =  j + 1)
        {
            if(num[i] % j == 0)
            {
                cont = cont + 1;    
            }
        }
    }
    if(cont == 2)
    {
        primo = primo + num[i];
        printf(" t ");
    }
}
printf("\n A soma dos numeros primos e: %d", primo);
getch();
```

Comment: Entendi a ideia, valeu , mas se eu zerar o cont na hora de declarar, eu preciso zerar ele de novo?
Não entendi o porque.

Comment: Sim, quando você zera na declaração o cont inicia com valor igual a zero, mas image que o primeiro número informado seja primo, quando for processar o segundo número, cont vai continuar com valor igual a 2, por isso você precisa zerar novamente

Comment: Nesse seu caso com um simples teste de mesa você já acharia o problema, recomendo você aprender mais sobre teste de mesa

Comment: É, preciso dar mais valor pro teste de mesa, vou me atentar com isso.
Obrigado Rodrigo.

Answer (score 1):

O seu código para verificar se o número é primo precisa ficar dentro de uma função, onde você passa o número do for principal, e a rotina devolve se ele é um primo ou não. Dependendo do resultado, você soma.